# What is the SPListTemplateType or SPListTemplateId of ACL of an item?

Tags: events, sharepoint-2010

What is the SPListTemplateType or SPListTemplateId or ListUrl of the list that appears when clicking on the item permission button on the edit control block or the button on the ribbon of any item  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010 you'll not be able to hookup an eventreceiver to catch any changes made here. [Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44842/what-is-the-splisttemplatetype-or-splisttemplateid-or-listurl-of-acl-of-an-item) is the full answer for my question.